# How to create proper xml attribute with python parser

Tags: python, xml, parsing

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

dom = parse('abc.xml')

for node in dom.getElementsBy('addr'): 
    print node.toxml()
```

What do i need to add (attribute) to print only addr's ( ip addresses from nmap xml file) ?

```
<host starttime="1404053959" endtime="1404054014"><status state="up" reason="reset" reason_ttl="254"/> <address addr="ip" addrtype="ipv4"/>
```

Comment: You need to add part of `abc.xml` file in your question.

Comment: well its is typical nmap xml file.
it goes like : 
<host starttime="1404053959" endtime="1404054014"><status state="up" reason="reset" reason_ttl="254"/>
<address addr="ip" addrtype="ipv4"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add `root` tag and `127.0.0.1`, `192.168.0.1` to show something more:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString

data = '''<root>
<host starttime="1404053959" endtime="1404054014">
    <status state="up" reason="reset" reason_ttl="254"/>
    <address addr="ip" addrtype="ipv4">127.0.0.1</address>
</host>
<host starttime="1404053959" endtime="1404054014">
    <status state="up" reason="reset" reason_ttl="254"/>
    <address addr="ip" addrtype="ipv4">192.168.0.1</address>
</host>
</root>'''

#dom = parse('abc.xml')
dom = parseString(data)

for node in dom.getElementsByTagName('address'):
    print ' xml:', node.toxml()
    print 'type:', node.getAttribute('addrtype')
    print 'addr:', node.childNodes[0].data
```

result:

```
 xml: <address addr="ip" addrtype="ipv4">127.0.0.1</address>
type: ipv4
addr: 127.0.0.1
 xml: <address addr="ip" addrtype="ipv4">192.168.0.1</address>
type: ipv4
addr: 192.168.0.1
```